# rename lists using a different list in IronPython

Tags: ironpython

I have a simple question, using IronPython I want to create a list of empty lists:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list_of_lists = [[] for i in names]
```

Then assign to each empty list, a specific name from the "names" list:

I can create a dictionary and access the lists like that:

```
new_names_dict = dict(zip(names, list_of_lists))

new_names_dict['a'] = []
```

But I'm looking for direct renaming without help of a dictionary.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you want to create variables in order to access them in the scope ?

Comment: for now I would be ok just to figure out how to rename them in the manner I described. The issue is that each project that this part of the script will be used, it will have a different number of lists that I need to initialize, then populate with data. So my big hurdle is  re-name the initialized lists based on the nomenclature extracted from each particular project. thanks for your help.

Comment: but you want to store these lists inside a dict ? or give a variable name to each one in order to access them easily in your code ?  If you need to map names to these lists, i think the dictionary is a good approach. You can do it in a shorter way : `new_names_dict  = {k:[] for k in names}`

Comment: thank you for your help.  what I want first is to give a var name to each list (based on the list I extract from the data) so I can associate each initialized list with a name, then access the list based on the newly associated name. for ex. if I create a list aa = ['1'], once I call it I get >>> aa['1'], so the same here: I initialize  the list of lists, then for each list I should have an assoc. name. If I run your code, it will not associate the list outside the dict. >>> a Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>NameError: name 'a' is not defined - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to create variables in order to access them in the current module is to update the `globals` dictionary, containing all variables of the global scope :

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

globals().update({k:[] for k in names})

print(a)
# >>> []
```